# RX String on UART not working

Tags: avr, serial, atmega, uart, receiver

I am having some problems with UART communication with the RN-42 SM Bluetooth module. Currently, I am just using polling to get communication going. I have my source files below.

The problems is that I can send properly, however cannot receive. I have been able to receive PARTS of a response, but it seems that the Transmit, sends a command before I can receive the whole buffer.

Note also that I am trying to retrieve a string of values. So for example, if I send a '$$$', I get a 'CMD\r\n' in return. I am trying to retrieve the latter.

SOURCE FILE

```
DDRC |= 0xFF;
DDRD |= 0xFA;

initUART();
unsigned char pinRTS = 0;
unsigned char buffer[RXBUFSIZE] = {0};

UNSETCTS(PORTD);

while(1)
{
    PORTC ^= 0xFF;
    pinRTS = GETRTS(PIND);

    if(pinRTS == 0x00) { //Receiver is letting us send
        SETCTS(PORTD);
        transmitStr((unsigned char *)CMDMODE);  
        UNSETCTS(PORTD); 

        waitForRcv();
        rcvStr(buffer);

        SETCTS(PORTD);  
        transmitStr((unsigned char *)EXITCMD); 
        UNSETCTS(PORTD); 

        waitForRcv();
        rcvStr(buffer);        
    }             
}
```

HEADER BELOW

```
#include "serial.h"

void initUART() {   
    /* Set baud rate */
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(UBBRVAL >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)UBBRVAL;

    /* Enable receiver and transmitter */
    UCSR0B = (1<<RXEN0)|(1<<TXEN0);

    /* Set frame format: 8 data, 1 stop bit */
    UCSR0C = (3<<UCSZ00);

    /* Double the speed */
    UCSR0A |= (1 << U2X0);
}

void USART_TRANSMIT(unsigned char cmd) {
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) );

    /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
    UDR0 = cmd;
}

void transmitStr(unsigned char *cmd) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; cmd[i] != '\0' ;i++) {
        USART_TRANSMIT(cmd[i]);
    }    
}

unsigned char USART_RECEIVE()
{
    /* Wait for data to be received */
    while ( !(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)) );

    /* Get and return received data from buffer */
    return UDR0;
}

void rcvStr(unsigned char *buffer) {
    int i = 0;
    while ( UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0) )  {
        buffer[i] = UDR0;
        i++;
    }   
    UCSR0A |= (1 << RXC0); 
}

void waitForRcv()
{
    while ( !((UCSR0A >> RXC0) & 0x01) );
}
```

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're properly watching to see if the bluetooth module has filled up it's RX buffer?  I'm really just not sure you're checking the RTS and CTS flags properly.

You should be checking the RTS and CTS flags every character, not just when you begin to send the whole string!  If you fill up the RX buffer on the bluetooth module, currently you'll keep transmitting, even if the RTS or CTS flags change.

You should also check which version of handshaking your module uses:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rs232#RTS.2FCTS_handshaking

Last but not least, small nit-pick: Are you actually storing source code in a header?  Please don't!  Put the source in a separate file and just put the prototypes in the header!

Comment: sorry ... the source code is not in the header ... lol i meant that is the implementation of the header... I will have a look at what you said... thanks for the help..

Comment: I connected to a logic analyzer to monitor the RTS coming from the Bluetooth module. It's strange, no matter how much data I keep sending it, it never sends a RTS response back telling me to stop sending.

Comment: How about the CTS flag (which would be the "clear-to-send" an indication that you, the sender, are allowed to transmit)

Comment: the CTS is an input to the Bluetooth and I assert it everytime I send a CMD to the bluetooth.

I have successfully managed to get the settings to work but using simple delays, however not being able to receive properly makes my firmware very incomplete. 

I have been able to retrieve the things coming from the RX side however, the message I receive tends to have bits from an earlier response mixed with parts of the current response but not all of it.

Comment: So if it is an input, CTS is meant to indicate that the bluetooth module is "clear" to transmit to you, the receiver.  You should not assert it during transmit, you should assert it when you have space in your receive buffer.

Comment: oh damn.. I completely overlooked that... I was using the CTS incorrectly... Thanks.. man now I feel stupid hahaah :( thanks for the help